# About Exact Sequences

Tags: abstract-algebra, exact-sequence

Suppose I have the following exact sequence:

$$\begin{matrix}
A_0& \xrightarrow{\quad\quad} & B_0   \xrightarrow{\quad\alpha\quad} & C_0\\ \uparrow&&&\downarrow \\ 
   C_1   & \xleftarrow{\quad\beta\quad}& B_1  \xleftarrow{\quad\quad}& A_1 
\end{matrix}$$

Then I obtain two short exact sequence using $ \alpha$ and $ \beta$ ( Kernels and cokernels ) with $A_0$ and $A_1$ in the middle.

Any help as to how I get these sequences?

Thanks!

Comment: I have edited your question; tell me if that's correct.

Comment: No :( It's a sequence of 6 terms, $\beta$ goes from $B_1$ to $C_1$ and there's a map from $ C_0$ to $A_1$.

Comment: Maybe my edit is better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
 0\longrightarrow \operatorname{Coker} \beta\longrightarrow A_0\longrightarrow \operatorname{Ker\alpha}\longrightarrow0
$$
because, by the exactness of the original sequence, $\operatorname{Im}(A_0\to B_0)=\operatorname{Ker}\alpha$ and $\operatorname{Ker}(A_0\to B_0)=C_1/\operatorname{Im}\beta\equiv\operatorname{Coker}\beta$.

The second sequence is similar.

Comment: Similar as in $$
 0\longrightarrow \operatorname{Coker\alpha} \longrightarrow A_1\longrightarrow \operatorname{Ker\beta}\longrightarrow0
$$??

Comment: Yes sure. Just rotate your original sequence (counter)clockwise  by $180^\circ$ and you will see that all you need is to change  the subscripts $0\to1$, $1\to0$.